# how to access a dictionary key value in the other key of same dictionary

Tags: python

i am new to python and not getting a way to access the dictionary value in another key of same dictionary.

```
keys = {
'sample': some_data,
'sample2': keys['sample']
}
```

The above codeblock gives an TypeError: 'module' object is not subscriptable

Is there anything like this keyword in python to do so.

Comment: ...replace `keys['sample']` with `some_data`?

Comment: The dictionary isn’t created before you try to pull values from it.

Comment: I suspect there's an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/) underlying your question. What are you trying to accomplish? – What's your overarching goal?

Comment: Did you actually get TypeError? In Python 3.6.6 I get `NameError: name 'keys' is not defined` which points directly to the problem that others have mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `keys` dictionary doesn't exist when you reference it. You need to define it before referencing it.

This code runs just fine:

```
some_data = 'xxx'

keys = {
'sample': some_data,
}

keys['sample2'] = keys['sample']
print(keys['sample2'])
```

Output:

```
>>> xxx
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your dictionary, you are trying to reference keys inside the keys dictionary itself. Which is impossible since you haven't defined keys in the first place (Circular reference).

The easiest way to avoid it to just do.

```
keys = {
'sample': some_data,
'sample2': some_data
}
```